# Can someone explain the host argument in BPF

Tags: winpcap, bpf

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and I can't find any answers online. Looking up the documentation doesn't really help. I don't understand what the argument `host` in a BPF code is supposed to represent or how to use it properly. Does it work the same way as `net`? (not saying I know what `net` does, I just assumed they might be similar) Please help.

Comment: Are you referring to the tcpdump syntax? Could you add an example of BPF code with host?

Answer (score 2):

`host` can be used to match a destination or source IP address in packets, whereas `net` can be used to match all IPs in a subnet and takes a CIDR. For example:

```bash
# matches all packets with 192.168.1.1 as source or destination IP address:
host 192.168.1.1
# matches all packets with destination IP address 192.168.1.1
dst host 192.168.1.1
# matches all packets with a source IP address within 192.168.1.0-255 
src net 192.168.1.0/24
```

Note that `host 192.168.1.1` is equivalent to `net 192.168.1.1/32`.

**Source:** This is all documented at https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html.